# How do I determine who fired onContextItemSelected?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am using an ExpandableListView, same way they do in this sample code:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html

The ExpandableListView gets populated with categories and their subcategories (once I click on a category). Example:
-Dairy  (category)
    -Milk (sub category)
    -cheese (sub category)

When I long-click on milk or cheese, a menu pops up using this function:

```
@Override 
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info =(ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) menuInfo;
    String selectedWord = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
    menu.setHeaderTitle(selectedWord.split(",")[1]);   //set header
    String itemId = selectedWord.split(",")[0];
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", "getProducts"));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("subcat_id", itemId));
    String response = helper.makeHttpRequest(nameValuePairs);
    String[] items = response.split(";");

    for (int i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, items[i]);
    }
}
```

Then, when I click on one of the items in the menu that pops up, I want to know which item in the list was selected (If I click on 'milk'. for example, the menu has "1% milk", "2% milk" etc._
This function gets fired:

```
    @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    ExpandableListContextMenuInfo info = (ExpandableListContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    String title = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
    String selected="";
    int type = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionType(info.packedPosition);
    if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_CHILD) {
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title + " selected: " + selected+ " " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else if (type == ExpandableListView.PACKED_POSITION_TYPE_GROUP) {
        int childPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionChild(info.packedPosition); 
        int groupPos = ExpandableListView.getPackedPositionGroup(info.packedPosition); 
        Toast.makeText(this, title  + " selected: " + selected + " " + childPos + " clicked in group " + groupPos , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

But I don't find a way to determine which item exactly in the list was clicked.

Any ideas? 
Thank you in advance! Please let me know if I need to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each item that you add to the `ContextMenu` should have its own unique identifier. This is useful for when you need to figure out which menu item was selected. So adding menu items needs to look like this: `menu.add(0, unique_id, 0, items_name);`. Then when you want to determine which item was selected you do something like this in `onContextItemSelected` using the item id:

```
switch (item.getItemId()){
    case UNIQUE_ID_1:
        //handle what to do
    break;
    case UNIQUE_ID_2:
        //handle what to do
    break;
    ....
```

So you may need to change your implementation slightly. I would create a unique id as an `int` constant for each possible case and add each one specifically to the menu. It may a little more code but it will be so much easier to handle.

Also just a suggestion since you are new here: when someone provides a good answer, you should accept it by clicking the check mark next to the answer. Good luck!